# BlackJack game not working Java

Tags: java, runtime-error, shuffle, blackjack

Here's pretty much my issue in steps.
1. I shuffle my deck and display cards to make sure it shuffled (works perfectly).
2. I play my blackjack game, work perfectly.
3. I shuffle my deck again and display cards again and it doesnt't work.
Answers to some questions you guys might ask:
1. The whole program is in a big while loop, the program doesn't end unless i select exit game as an option.
2. I have tried to display my deck again without shuffling it a second time and it works fine.

```
 public Card deal()
 {
     Card temp;
     temp = storage[top];
     storage[top] = null;
     top++;
     return temp;
 }

 public void shuffle()
 {

int n = storage.length;
for (int i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) 
    {
    // Get a random index of the array past i.
    int random = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n - i));
    // Swap the random element with the present element.
    Card randomElement = storage[random];
    storage[random] = storage[i];
    storage[i] = randomElement;
 }
 }

public void display ()
{
    for (int i = top; i<52; i++)
        storage[i].display();

}
```

Here is my stack trace
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
J of C
    at blackjack.Deck.display(Deck.java:104)
    at blackjack.BlackJack.main(BlackJack.java:55)
Java Result: 1

```
case 3:
    {
      myDeck.display();
      break;
    }
```

and my code from deck.display

```
public void display ()
{
    for (int i = top; i<storage.length; i++)
        storage[i].display();

}
```

Comment: can you provide us with stack trace ? also you could use [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to shuffle.

Comment: It would help to have the full code, if it's not super long.

Comment: "and display cards again and it doesnt't work" In what way does it not work? What does it do or not do? Please be specific.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You never reset your top variable, I think you need to do that. 
Post your stack trace and the rest of your code, too.

Comment: Good grief, post the whole thing so we can at least see what line number 55 *actually is*